# Taylor series, Laurent series and a simple pole

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

> Let $f$ be holomorphic in $|z|<2$ except for $z=1$, in which it has a simple pole. Let $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n$ be the Taylor series of $f$ around $z=0$. Prove or find a counterexample:
>
> (A) $a_n$ doesn't necessarily converge.
>
> (B) $a_n$ converges and $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = -Res(f,1)$.
>
> (C) $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ converges.
>
> (D) $a_n\neq 0 $ for every $n$ and $\sum_{n=-\infty}^0 \frac{1}{a_{-n}} z^n$ is the Laurent
> series of $f$ in $1<|z|<2$.
>
> (E) There exists a $z_0$ with $|z_0|>1$ for which $\sum _{n=0}^\infty$
> converges.

The only parts I know how to solve are:
(C) is wrong since it represents the value of the Taylor series at $z=1$ which we know doesn't converge because the function has a simple pole there.

(B) looks true, but I don't know how to approach it. I guess there is some use of the Residue theorem, not sure how to prove that $\frac{1}{2\pi i }\int \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz \to -Res(f,1)$ as $n$ tends to infinity.

In $D$ I thought that in such a case $z=1$ would be an essential singularity, but wasn't sure.

Thank you!

Comment: For (B) see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2265603/42969

Comment: I suggest analyzing $(z-1)f(z).$